# При центрировании карты установленная метка смещается относительно заданных координат

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите,  пожалуйста, в чем м.б. проблема. Написал код, чтобы при клике по населенному пункту карта центрировалась на городе (не баунд)

```js
myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
  // Получение координат щелчка
  var coords = e.get('coords');

  //Получаем объекты "нас.пункты"
  var myReverseGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(coords, {kind:'locality' });

  myReverseGeocoder.then(function (res) {

    // Установим центр карты на ближайшем городе
    myMap.setCenter(res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates(), myMap.action.getCurrentState().zoom, { duration: 1000 });

    // Добавим точку на карту
    myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects.get(0));
    },
    function (err) {
      alert('Ошибка');
    }
  );
});
```

В результате при первом клике по карте ставится точка на ближайшем городе, далее идет центрирование карты, город "уезжает" в центр карты, НО установленная точка остается на месте относительно Layout (Т.е. смещается относительно первоначально установленных координат на карте и относительно выбранного города). После того, как карта отцентрировалась на нужном месте - точка тоже устанавливается в нужную координату.
При установке последующих точек все происходит корректно - маркер центрируется вместе с городом

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/xag13e6f/4

Comment: Соберите пример воспроизводящий проблему на https://jsfiddle.net/xag13e6f/ без примера непонятно что происходит.

Comment: @se0ga Если правильно использовал jsfiddle, то https://jsfiddle.net/xag13e6f/4/
Необходимо кликнуть по какому-либо месту (городу), не в центре карты

Comment: Можно сначала создать метку, а потом её перемещать https://jsfiddle.net/6ay98wqp/

Comment: Спасибо! работает )